Insert newline above current line?
Let's assume I am in INSERT mode and my cursor is just after * in the following line.
This is * a line of text.

I would like to know of some shortcut key or a mapping to insert a new line before this line and take the rest of the text after * to previous line. It should look like this:
 a line of text.
This is *

I tried to look it up as best as I can, but didn't find it anywhere. Apologies if this question already exists.

There is nothing built-in that does exactly what you want. In such a case, you are expected to: 1. Figure out a macro that does what you want, no matter how much keys you need to press. 2. Turn that macro in a custom mapping. Which part of this do you have trouble with, exactly?

I would do <CR><Esc>ddP (but I don't think it's worth an answer of its own)

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

I would do (with vim-unimpaired):
<Esc>lD[p


Esc leave insert mode
lD cut the rest of the line
[p paste above the line

I would do without vim-unimpaired:
<Esc>lDO<Esc>p


Esc leave insert mode
lD cut the rest of the line
O add a line above
Esc leave insert mode
p paste


[p is not linewise unless remapped (by vim-unimpaired or custom mapping or whatever).

@Matt thanks for you comment (I'm so used to vim-unimpaired :-)

@VivianDeSmedt Thanks a lot for this great answer.

You are welcome! Thanks for the feedback :-)
